# How to store images in mysql and retrieve and display them through jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp, jdbc

i am working with jdbc,mysql,html,jsp.i want to store an image into database through jdbc code
and retrive and display them using jsp.please help urgently.I'm creating an online shopping website as a project.

Comment: Where are the code you already done ?

Comment: Follow the link, you might get some help. http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/jsp/threads/254530/uploading-image-to-mysql-using-htmljsp-form..-need-help

Answer (score 1):

*This is very simple to store an image in MySQL database using JSP :*

Go Step By Step:

**Step 1- Create this table in database**

```
create table upload_image
(
    iImageID int AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    bImage longblob
);
```

**Step2- Save This code as uploadimage.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java"  errorPage="" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Image insert into database</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="frm" action="saveImage.jsp" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
 <input type="file" name="uProperty" /> <br>
 <input type="submit" name="goUpload" value="Upload" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Step3- Save This code as  saveImage.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.io.output.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%
   Connection conn=null;
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gimtech","root", "harit");

   PreparedStatement psImageInsertDatabase=null;

   byte[] b=null;
   try{
      String sqlImageInsertDatabase="insert into upload_image (bImage) values(?)";
      psImageInsertDatabase=conn.prepareStatement(sqlImageInsertDatabase);

      DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

      ServletFileUpload sfu = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
      List items = sfu.parseRequest(request);

      Iterator iter = items.iterator();

      while (iter.hasNext()) {
         FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
         if (!item.isFormField()) {
              b = item.get();
          }
      }

      psImageInsertDatabase.setBytes(1,b);
      psImageInsertDatabase.executeUpdate();
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
     e.printStackTrace();
     response.sendRedirect("addimage.jsp");
   }

%>
```

And you should must add the jar files:

1. [commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/index.html)
2. [commons-io-1.4.jar](http://commons.apache.org/io/)
3. [mysql-connector-java-5.1.5-bin.jar](http://www.mysql.com/)

Comment: Do you like this scriptlets? :)

Comment: @Tiny, i think you didn't look my post, watch clearly...

Comment: I was just talking about scriptlets in JSP which is highly discouraged for over a decade and should be [avoided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202).

Comment: What is the meaning of `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: Hello, i am creating connection on beans component, but after importing all zip files to `lib`, compiler says: `package org.apache.commons.fileupload.*; does not exists`.

Comment: How to retrieve the image from the database ?